# Move rooftop air conditioner 20cm: What type of anchors are preferable?

Tags: roof

On a single story flat roof private home I need to move a rooftop air conditioning radiator 20 cm for a solar panel install. Fortunately the sloppy original install left enough electrical cable and refrigerant hose dangling whereas I do not need to concern myself with them. All I need to do is remove the four bolts in the roof, remount in the new location, and seal the original holes.

The house was constructed in 2017. The roof is concrete with a tar-like blanket on top. I do not know how thick the blanket or roof are.

**What type of anchors are preferable?** Will the fact that the new holes are only 20cm from the old holes affect the type of anchor recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Remove one of the bolts and take it to your home store. The bolt will give you a great idea on how deep the hole is that you need. Also, based on the threads, you or the people at the home store should get some sort of idea on the type of anchor that the bolt goes into, like lag shields and lag bolts verses a smooth thread. The distance of 20 cm won't make a difference. Personally, I prefer lag shields and lag bolts for any concrete anchoring.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the same as the original anchors. They did the job then, why wouldn't they now? Just make sure they go through similar to what they went through previously - which should be sturdy wood of some kind.

Comment: I do not know what the original anchors were, I did not do the original install. I do not expect the anchors to come out with the old bolts.

Comment: So far as I know, there is no wood in this roof. Only concrete.

Comment: When the bolts come out, you'll know what they are, and be able to see the fixings, though, won't you? And if you don't know how thick the roof is, how can we help? The thickness may be revealed by the length of the bolts.

Comment: I've never been able to see an anchor inside a bolthole, ever, and especially do not expect to be able to with the tar-like mat in place. I do agree that the length of the bolt will help me determine factors such as the thickness of the roof, and how far to drill. Thank you.